# How to save user input to mySQL, getting FATAL ERROR (php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, undefined

I'm getting a fatal error "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null' in C:\Users\Aushkia\Desktop\PHP Class\new.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Aushkia\Desktop\PHP Class\new.php(20): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Aushkia\Desktop\PHP Class\new.php on line 20"

And also it is saying that my index for lines 5-7 are Undefined Index.

This is my last project for this class, and I can't seem to find how to solve this issue, and everything I have looked up is for other python or java. And to boot I have to be in the hospital in an hour and a half for my baby being born! lol. Anyhow, here is my code, any help would be awesome, thanks in advance!!

```
<?php
session_start();

 /* Data input */
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Description = $_POST['Description'];
$Price = $_POST['Price'];


/* login section */

require("auth.php");

/* sql input  */

$db = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php", "admin", "123" );
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmnt = $db->prepare( "insert into products (name, description, price)values(:name, :description, :price)" );
$stmnt->execute( array( 'name' => $Name, 'description' => $Description, 'price' => $Price ));


$results = $db->query( 'select * from products' ); 

$products = $results->fetchAll();   


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--  UPDATED TO AUTHENTIACTION -->
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>new item</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stl.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"> 
</head> 
<p>
<a href="show.php" class="button">Home</a>
<a href="new.php" class="button">Add New</a>
<a href="login.view.php" class="button">Login</a>
<a href="logout.php" class="button">Logout</a>
</P>
<body>


<div align="Center">

<h1>item info</h1><hr/>



<form action="new.php" method="post">


<label for="name">Name:</label><br />
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" id="Name">
<br />

<label for="desciption">Description :</label><br />
<input name="desciption" type="text" placeholder="Description" value="" id="Description">
<br />

<label for="price">Price :</label><br />
<input name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price" value="" id="Price">
<br />



<p><input type="submit" value="save"></p>

</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the error is self explanatory, you should be able to solve this

Comment: You most likely need to put all the `$_POST` and database insert related code in a block where you check whether an actual POST request was made.

Comment: In all fairness the error is pretty self-explanatory as @kapil.dev said.

Comment: I think he didn't get the difference between id and name ;)

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence, but I would have asked on here if I haven't been searching for error meanings for the past 2 hours. I am generally confused on how it is pulling as NULL.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) and check what fields are you getting.

Comment: `$stmnt->execute( array( 'name' => $Name, 'description' => $Description, 'price' => $Price )`  should be : `$stmnt->execute( array( ':name' => $Name, ':description' => $Description, ':price' => $Price ));`

Answer (score 0):

You must learn to debug your own code, the errors and notices you are getting are self explanatory as they have said in the comments.

First the undefined indexes notice

> Undefined index mean that the entry was not found in the array. In
>   your  case,  $_POST['Name'] , $_POST['Description']; $_POST['Price'] 
>   doesn't exist in the $_POST array.

**in your form you do not have input type with the above name attributes. NB there's a fine line between Name and name, Price and price, Description and description.**

You are getting the fatal error on pdo because you are inserting a null value on a column that must be not null. the base of your error comes from the above explanation,

PDO uses prepared statements with placeholders like:

```
:placeholdername,:placeholdername2
```

when you execute them you write the placeholder as it is

```
execute(array(':placeholdername'=>$identifiers,':placeholdername2'=>identifier2)
```

in your case these `$stmnt->execute( array( 'name' => $Name, 'description' => $Description, 'price' => $Price ));` does not exist.

or you use "?" as a placeholder:

your code should be

```
<?php
session_start();
/* login section */

require("auth.php");

/* sql input  */

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php", "admin", "123");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$errors = "";

if (isset($_POST['btnName'])) {

    //check if inputs are not empty

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {

        echo "enter name";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $Name = $_POST['name'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['desciption'])) {

        echo "enter desciption";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $Description = $_POST['desciption'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['price'])) {

        echo "enter price";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $Price = $_POST['price'];
    }


    if ($errors <= 0) {
        //No errors insert

       try {

             $stmnt = $db->prepare("insert into products (name, description, price)values(:name, :description, :price)");
        $stmnt->execute(array(
            ':name' => $Name,
            ':description' => $Description,
            ':price' => $Price
        ));

        echo "records added";

       } catch (PDOException $e) {


            echo "error : ".$e->getMessage();

       }



    }


}
?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--  UPDATED TO AUTHENTIACTION -->
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>new item</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stl.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"> 
</head> 
<p>
<a href="show.php" class="button">Home</a>
<a href="new.php" class="button">Add New</a>
<a href="login.view.php" class="button">Login</a>
<a href="logout.php" class="button">Logout</a>
</P>
<body>


<div align="Center">

<h1>item info</h1><hr/>



<form action="new.php" method="post">


<label for="name">Name:</label><br />
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" id="Name">
<br />

<label for="desciption">Description :</label><br />
<input name="desciption" type="text" placeholder="Description" value="" id="Description">
<br />

<label for="price">Price :</label><br />
<input name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price" value="" id="Price">
<br />

<p><input type="submit" value="save" name="btnName"></p>

</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Or with "?" placeholders**

```
<?php
session_start();
/* login section */

require("auth.php");

/* sql input  */

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php", "admin", "123");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$errors = "";

if (isset($_POST['btnName'])) {

    //check if inputs are not empty

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {

        echo "enter name";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $Name = $_POST['name'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['desciption'])) {

        echo "enter desciption";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $Description = $_POST['desciption'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['price'])) {

        echo "enter price";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $Price = $_POST['price'];
    }


    if ($errors <= 0) {
        //No errors insert

       try {

             $stmnt = $db->prepare("insert into products (name, description, price)values(?,?,?)");
        $stmnt->execute(array($Name,$Description,$Price));

        echo "records added";

       } catch (PDOException $e) {


            echo "error : ".$e->getMessage();

       }



    }


}
?>
```

> NB: for your own good it's better to filter and sanitize input from a
>   user before u can save it

Comment: Yo @MasivuyeCokile thanks man, just got back from the hospital today. And checked back up on this. My professor's way was a lil different, and this is way easier to read/understand.

Comment: @Aushkia if this helped you solved your problem, upvote then mark as correct, so that we can know tht u found a solution